# How do I avoid cross site errors when using the google web store API?

Tags: javascript, chrome-web-store

I'm trying to follow this simple examples given in the google web store API docs. 
Unfortunately their minimal PHP example contains a lot of stuff I dont need (and dont have setup).

So I'm looking at hardcoding the basic stuff into the HTML file, just to get communication with the google servers working:

My code looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      purchase = function() { console.log("Old purchase function"); }
        generatedJwt = "..."; // I use a real JWT here....
        google.load('payments', '1.0', {
          'packages': ['sandbox_config'],
          callback: function()
          {
            //Success handler
            var successHandler = function(purchaseAction){
              if (window.console != undefined) {
                console.log("Purchase completed successfully.",purchaseAction);
           }
          }

          //Failure handler
          var failureHandler = function(purchaseActionError)
          {
             if (window.console != undefined)
             {
            console.log("Purchase did not complete.", purchaseActionError);
         }
           }

           var purchase = function()
           {
          goog.payments.inapp.buy({
                 'jwt'     : generatedJwt,
                 'success' : successHandler,
                 'failure' : failureHandler
              });
           }
        }
      });
   </script>
   <button class="buy-button" id="buybutton1" name="buy" type="button" onClick="purchase()">
      Buy
   </button>
 </body>
```

When I click on the buy button I get an error message pop up from google, and the following error in the console:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL   
http://localhost/google_iap/buy_page.html 
from frame with URL
https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/static/gwt/payments.html?viewportScreenCenterX=-857.5&viewportScreenCenterY=611#id=I1_1324454042050&parent=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&rpctoken=166967692&_methods=onPurchaseActionStatus%2CgetJwt%2C_ready%2C_close%2C_open%2C_resizeMe.
Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

What do I need to do to make this simple example work?

**Addendum:**

I found a nicer example from google:

https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/customer/gadget/inapp/demo.html

However saving the source to my machine and accessing it locally ( as http://localhost/google_iap/google_demo.html ) gives the same cross-domain error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the [google sandbox was broken](https://groups.google.com/group/in-app-payments/t/259ceae1ae1a9be2). This is now working again, so the example seems to functions correctly. However warnings about cross site access still exist.